# multiple variables in routes. A route isn't leading to the controller defined blade

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have "show" and "edit" two routes. It's showing two different url.  But "edit" route is using the 'show' blade, which is the SAME as the "show" route. How to lead the "edit" route to the 'edit' blade?

here is the web.php:

```
  Route::get('/{user}/{course}', 'CoursesController@show')->name('course.show');
  Route::get('/{user}/edit_{course}', 'CoursesController@edit')->name('course.edit');
```

here is the controller:

```
   public function edit(Course $course) {
   return view('courses.edit', compact('course'));
   }
   public function show(Course $course) {
   return view('courses.show', compact('course'));
   }
```

here is the index blade:

```
  <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" href="{{ route("course.show", [auth()->user()->username, $course->title. $course->id] ) }}"> VIEW </a>
  <a class="btn btn-xs btn-info" href="{{ route("course.edit", [auth()->user()->username, $course->title. $course->id]) }}"> EDIT </a>
```

Comment: Do you have the files ```views/courses/edit.blade.php``` and ```views/courses/show.blade.php```? If so, I'm not sure what the problem is clearly.

Comment: Are you passing in the correct request?

Comment: you edit and show methods must receive the id of the model in order the model binding can work properly. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding

Comment: change the order of the two routes solved the issue. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order or your routes in your routes files web.php

```php
Route::get('/{user}/edit_{course}', 'CoursesController@edit')->name('course.edit'); //This one goes first.
Route::get('/{user}/{course}', 'CoursesController@show')->name('course.show');
```

Your `show` route is working as a wildcard if you invert the order as shown the edit route will catch it first when the second variable begins with `edit_`.

Comment: Yaasss you are absolutely right. Thanks a lot victoryoalli!!!